# inheritance view and adding fields

Tags: odoo-8

i have candidat model inherit the hr.emplyee model
i want to display the form view of hr.employee and add fields of my child model candidat

```
class hr_candidat(models.Model):
_name='hr_recrutement.candidat'
_inherit='hr.employee'
_description="Informations du Candidats"

situation=fields.Selection(string="Situation",selection=[('Nouveau','Nouveau'),('RDV Thechnique','RDV Technique'),('Annulation','Annulationn')])
```

.
.
.

```
<record id="hr_recrutement_candidat_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Candidat</field>
        <field name="model">hr_recrutement.candidat</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Candidat">
                <sheet>
                    <group>
                        <field name="situation" />
                        .
                        .
                    </group>
                </sheet>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

I dont know how to display fields of hr.employee + my fields of candidat in view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just we should set the below code from the view xml file and also 
 add the depended **module as hr** in your **openerp**.py and set the view xml file path as well.

**Add below code in your .py file**

```
class hr_employee(models.Model):
_inherit='hr.employee'
_description="Informations du Candidats"

situation=fields.Selection(string="Situation",selection=[('Nouveau','Nouveau'),('RDV Thechnique','RDV Technique'),('Annulation','Annulationn')])
```

**Add below code in your .xml file**

```
<record id="hr_recrutement_caindidat_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Candidat</field>
    <field name="model">hr.employee</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_employee_form" />
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
          <xpath expr="field[@name='work_location']" position="after">
                <field name="situation" />
          </xpath>
   </field>
</record>
```

Hear We have to set the position of your element based on **xpath** using `before,after,inside,replace` **Attributes** of xpath tag.

I hope my answer may helpful for you :)

Comment: I do not want to rewrite the hr.employee view , i want to inherit the view and adding a new fileds without change the original hr.employee form